# Error in compiling SenTestingKit while using google navigation in ios app

Tags: swift, architecture, ios-simulator, x86-64, dylib

I am getting error while i am compiling my project.

> "building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for
>   MacOSX file '/Applications/Xcode
>   3.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework/SenTestingKit'
>   for architecture x86_64"

I have search this problem but couldnot get solution and i am stucked in this problem since 3-4 days.

Thanks

Comment: `SenTestingKit` is old, you should use `XCTest`, however probably that's not the cause of your problem. Are you still using `Xcode3`?

Comment: Did you recently created the unit testing target? If yes, did you somehow choose to the `Unit Testing` type from the `OSX` section instead of the `iOS` one from the `Xcode` target template?

Comment: Not getting what you are telling,sorry and i am using xcode 6.4

Comment: The error message refers to `Xcode 3.app`, that why I was asking. Anyhow check my second question (second comment)